# Determine longest "streak" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I looked at some of the other "Streak" questions, but nothing was quite the same as my situation as theirs included consecutive ID's.

I have the data shown below and I am attempting to determine the longest "day" streak each user has had of "Yes" proficiency without receiving a "No". The days aren't necessarily consecutive. Each day is effectively a work "Shift", so I'd like to be able to say "User X has had 8 shifts without a 'No'." for each user.

```
ProficiencyUser ProficiencyDateAdded       ProficiencyMet
JDOE            2016-04-09 19:35:51.590    Yes
RTHOMPSON       2016-04-09 19:16:42.237    Yes
MMOUSE          2016-04-09 18:59:03.263    Yes
MMOUSE          2016-04-09 18:54:33.210    Yes
MMOUSE          2016-04-09 18:26:55.750    No
MMOUSE          2016-04-06 18:54:33.210    Yes
MMOUSE          2016-03-26 13:54:33.210    Yes
MMOUSE          2016-04-09 18:54:33.210    Yes
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Can a user get a Yes and No in the same day as 2 different records?

Comment: Yes - As the sample data indicates, a user can receive both a Yes and No in the same day.

Comment: Can you add a relatively complex example with some combinations that are possible (e.g. Yes and No on the same day, No data for several days while the person is on vacation etc.) and show expected results for that example?

Comment: Added a couple more entries to original post. I am thinking this might be easier if I modify my requirements to calculate the number of days from today's date since their last "No". Will basically show only their "current" streak.

Comment: In the updated scenario, MMOUSE had a streak of 2 days (26th March through 6th Apr). Then MMOUSE had a streak of 1 day (9th Apr). Is that correct? I am looking at sorted data like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56c6c/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns the longest streak for each user:

```
;WITH
TestUser AS -- Convert 'Yes'/'No' to int
(
SELECT
    t.[ProficiencyUser]
    ,t.[ProficiencyDateAdded]
    ,ProficiencyMet = CASE WHEN t.[ProficiencyMet] = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM [Test] t
)
,ByDates AS -- Get Result per Day per User
(
SELECT
    u.[ProficiencyUser]
    ,ProficiencyDate = CAST(u.[ProficiencyDateAdded] AS date)
    ,ProficiencyMet = CASE WHEN COUNT(u.[ProficiencyMet]) = SUM(CAST(u.[ProficiencyMet] as int)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM [TestUser] u
GROUP BY [u].[ProficiencyUser], CAST(u.[ProficiencyDateAdded] AS date)
)
,UserDayRank AS -- rank user days
(
SELECT
    Id = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [ProficiencyUser] ORDER BY [ProficiencyDate])
    ,[ProficiencyUser]
    ,[ProficiencyDate]
    ,[ProficiencyMet]
FROM [ByDates]
)
,UserSeq AS -- filter user days, and get islands and gaps per user
(
SELECT
    [Id]
    ,[ProficiencyUser]
FROM [UserDayRank]
WHERE [ProficiencyMet] = 1
)
,Islands AS -- number each user's island
(
SELECT
    Id
    ,GroupId = Id - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ProficiencyUser] ORDER BY [Id])
    ,[ProficiencyUser]
FROM [UserSeq]
)
,IslandLen AS -- get length of user's islands
(
SELECT
    L = COUNT([GroupId])
    ,[ProficiencyUser]
FROM [Islands]
GROUP BY [ProficiencyUser], [GroupId]
)
-- finally get the longest user's island for each user
SELECT [ProficiencyUser], L = MAX(L) FROM [IslandLen]
GROUP BY [ProficiencyUser]
ORDER BY MAX(L) DESC, [ProficiencyUser]
```

Comment: Running this outputs a subset of the users with only Username column outputted (no streak)

Comment: Updated version works properly. So there's a lot going on there and I'm not too proficient with SQL to understand it all. Is the "count" that is being displayed a count of consecutive "shifts" each user has?

Comment: I have 1 user who's last "No" was on 3/19. With above SQL, he returns "7". When I run it from today minus that date, it's 22 days. What is the 7 representing?

Comment: Can you prepare some data in SqlFiddler and send me a link?

Answer (score 0):

In the modified requirements (see comments), here is what I came up that gives me the "streak" (number of days consecutively) from today's date to each user's last "No" entry:

```
SELECT l.*, DATEDIFF(DAY, l.ProficiencyDateAdded, GETDATE()) AS 'DaysAgo'
FROM
(SELECT ProficiencyUser, MAX(ProficiencyDateAdded) AS 'ProficiencyDateAdded'
FROM   ProficiencyTable
WHERE ProficiencyMet LIKE 'No'
GROUP BY ProficiencyUser) l
ORDER BY DaysAgo DESC
```